# What is the opposite of "Format"?

Tags: methods, naming-conventions

I am creating a business item formatter (spread) where while displaying i want to display the number after multiplying it by 100, and for all calculation purpose i want to read the number from display (TextBox), parse it to double and then divide it 100.

```
SpreadFormatter {
    public string Format(double originalValue){
         //Please dont mind this logic/approach. I am just represeting the scenario.
         return (originalValue * 100).ToString();
    }

    public double SuggestAName(string currentValue){
         //Please dont mind this logic/approach. I am just represeting the scenario.         
         return Double.Parse(currentValue)/100 ;
    }
}
```

I am looking for an appropriate name for "SuggestAName" method above.

Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tend to think of `Parse` as the opposite of `Format`. Either that, or I go the way of "from" and "to", e.g. `ToDisplayFormat` and `FromDisplayFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

`public double Parse(string currentValue)`